# 2nd Facebook Messenger Account Notifications

Tags: iphone-app, facebook

I am using an iPhone and have two Facebook accounts.  One for family and one for friends.

Currently notifications only work for the accounted selected in messenger(1 account).  I would like to have notifications for both accounts and notification number/badge next to 2 applications.  I have tried Friendly and it doesn't push notifications.  On my Android phone I use the lite app along with the official one.